# Is there a recommended way to setup keyboard listeners for your application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4

Is there a default method you use to capture application wide keyboard events?

I've found the NativeMenu lets me specify and capture keyboard events through the menu items. So I can create a MenuItem, add a listener to it and specify the keyboard modifier as "S" and "CTRL" for the "File Save" and when the user presses CTRL + "S" my handler catches it.

But, not everything will have a menu item so how do I handle those? What do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the keyboard events on the main stage - this way you will always get them everywhere in your application:

```
public function YourMainApplication()
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
}

private function onKeyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
        trace("CTRL + S was pressed");
    }
}
```